# Return a Color based on a String

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to select the color of a Shape based on a String enum that I have declared in my struct. I have a String "**red**" and I want to convert it to "**Color.red**" for example but I'm not sure how can I do that.

This is my current code

```
//
//  Feature.swift
//
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Feature: Equatable {
    private var number: Number
    private var shape: Shape
    private var shading: Shading
    private var color: ShapeColor
    
    init(number: Number, shape: Shape, shading: Shading, color: ShapeColor) {
        self.number = number
        self.shape = shape
        self.shading = shading
        self.color = color
    }
    
    static func ==(first: Feature, second: Feature) -> Bool {
        return first.shape == second.shape
    }
    
    func equals(compareWith: Feature) -> Bool {
        return self.shape == compareWith.shape
    }
    
    func getShape(card: Feature) -> some View {
        switch card.shape {
        case .diamond:
            return AnyView(VStack {
                ForEach(0..<card.number.rawValue, id: \.self) { number in
                    Diamond().foregroundColor(Color.purple) // <- This is where I want to use card.color for the Color
                }
            })
        case .squiggle:
            return AnyView(VStack {
                ForEach(0..<card.number.rawValue, id: \.self) { number in
                    Squiggle().foregroundColor(Color.red) // <- This is where I want to use card.color for the Color
                }
            })
        case .oval:
            return AnyView(VStack {
                ForEach(0..<card.number.rawValue, id: \.self) { number in
                    Circle().foregroundColor(Color.green) // <- This is where I want to use card.color for the Color
                }
            })
        }
    }
    
    enum Number: Int, CaseIterable {
        case one = 1, two, three
    }
    
    enum Shape: String, CaseIterable {
        case diamond, squiggle, oval
    }
    
    enum Shading: String, CaseIterable {
        case solid, striped, open // striped will be translucent to be easier
    }
    
    enum ShapeColor: String, CaseIterable {
        case red, green, purple
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the ShapeColor enum in a propertyWrapper.

```
@propertyWrapper
enum ShapeColor: String, CaseIterable {
    case red, green, purple
    
    var wrappedValue: Color {
        switch self {
        case .red: return Color.red
        case .purple: return Color.purple
        case .green: return Color.green
        }
    }
}
```

and change the initialization

```
@ShapeColor private var color: Color

init(number: Number, shape: Shape, shading: Shading, color: ShapeColor) {
    self.number = number
    self.shape = shape
    self.shading = shading
    self._color = color
}
```

and change the getShape returning the shapes to

```
Circle().foregroundColor(card.color)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked wonderfully. I'm still fairly new so I'm going to read about property wrappers. One quick question maybe you can help me with. I renamed my color property from Color to ShapeColor because it was getting mixed up with the Color Struct from Apple. Is there any way to use the same name for both or did I do the correct thing renaming it to ShapeColor? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `case .red: return .red`

Comment: This is just my opinion, but I think that it's better/ easier to avoid naming conflicts than to work around it, when you might use the type you've defined and the predefined one simultaneously. For eg, I might want to use a State enumeration to describe the state of a particular View, but it will conflict with the @State property wrapper. So, you are good with ShapeColor